# Identify a record that contain the phone Number with different format

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, wildcard, phone-number

I have three types of phone numbers in my SQL server table as below

[image]

Can someone please suggest how can I perform a search operation for below scenarios.

1. Search by 10 digit number  --- 029700456
2. Search by 10 digit number that was in the range --- 0294005623

Comment: The second requirement would be hard to come by using SQL Server.

Comment: can you please elaborate the second scenario and provide the expected output on the given input?

Comment: i would like to retrieve the record  when i search for the phone number  that was present in the range . for example searching 0294005623 should give me row with (+61) 0294005622-5624

Comment: @Kidoo Thanks! I think Gordon's answer does that perfectly, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all the numbers to a canonical format using `translate()` and `replace()`.  From the canonical format, you can define the upper and lower bound on the range, depending on whether the phone has 10 or 14 characters:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (values (case when phone like '(+61)%'
                   then stuff(replace(translate(t.phone, '()+-', '    '), ' ', ''), 1, 2, '')
                   else replace(translate(t.phone, '()+-', '    '), ' ', '')
              end)
     ) v(canonical)
     (values (left(canonical, 10),
              (case when len(canonical) = 10 then canonical
                    else left(canonical, 6) + right(canonical, 4)
               end)
              )
     ) v2(phone_upper, phone_lower)
```

Then your conditions are:

```
where @phone between v2.phone_lower and v2.phone_upper
```

I would advise you to figure out how to fix the data model.  This is a really, really, really bad way to store phone numbers and phone number ranges.